# Blazor WASM - API authorization disappears on refresh

Tags: azure, blazor, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly, microsoft-entra-id

I don't have a lot of experience in dotnet and authentication so I'm trying to wrap my head around this.

So I'm building a Blazor WASM app (.NET 8.0) for my company, we started from the blazor wasm template that includes authentication. So far this works wonderfully.

We also set up an API for this application that is deployed on an on-site Windows IIS server. We also have an API client for this API which is distributed on a private nuget feed via Azure DevOps.

My program.cs looks like this:

```cs
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
});


var authority = new AuthorityProvider();
var productsApiClient = new ProductsApiClient(
        authority,
        new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) }
    );

builder.Services.AddScoped<IProductsApiClient>(sp => productsApiClient);

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

An example api call looks like this in a component/page (omitted some irrelevant stuff):

```cs
@page "/products/{Id:guid}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@using Products.Contracts
@using Products.Contracts.API
@inject IProductsApiClient ApiClient
@attribute [Authorize]

<html/>

@code {
  [Parameter]
  public Guid Id { get; set; } = default!;
  private Product product { get; set; } = default!;

  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
  {
    product= await ApiClient.GetProduct(Id);
  }
}
```

In the backend that call looks like this:

```cs
public async Task<Product> Getproduct(Guid id)
        {
            if (!Authority.GetAllowed)
                throw new UnauthorizedAccessException(READ_ACTION_NOT_ALLOWED);

            var url = $"{this.BaseRoute}/{id}";

            var result = await _http.GetFromJsonAsync<Product>(url);

            if (result == null)
                return Product.Empty();

            this.Authority.Update(result.Links);

            return result;
        }
```

So far so good, app runs, I can log in, I can go to the overview page of all products, and I can go to a detail page of a product.

As you can see from the component snippet, my intention is that if a user gets sent a url for a product by a colleague, they can just click the link and they will immediately be on the correct page and the info for that product gets fetched, which is a pretty standard setup imo (if they're not logged in they are redirected to login first).

This is where I hit the limits of my understanding of azure authentication and dotnet and the problems begin, everything works fine, but when I click the link and it opens in a new tab, or if I just refresh the detail page I get the following error:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Read action not allowed.
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Read action not allowed.
```

As that is the error that is defined in the API to be thrown if we don't have the authorisation for that endpoint, it kind of makes sense. But what happened to my authorisation? If i refresh the page I'm still in the same tab, my session is still active, I don't have to log back in and I can still see my tokens in sessionStorage for that tab. So what is going wrong here exactly? Where is my auth going and how can I persist it across tabs/refreshes? Also when the calls do work (if I strictly use in app navigation) I don't see any form of authorisation headers or bearer tokens on the request. So how does this work under the hood?

I removed the authority check from the products endpoint that returns all products to test it, and on refresh that call works perfectly fine, so it has to be authorisation/authentication related... I've done a bunch of research but haven't found anything that actually explains this in depth. I feel like I'm missing something (obvious). Am I supposed to store my tokens in localStorage instead?

Does anyone have any advice or experience they can share?

I've pretty much tried everything, dotnet docs are very convoluted and hard to follow if you're new to dotnet, pretty much every github thread gets closed by microsoft bots, and the one stackoverflow post I found that seems to describe the same problem is from 3 years ago and the OP never came back with the answer.

Comment: `I click the link and it opens in a new tab, or if I just refresh the detail page I get the following error` and `when the calls do work (if I strictly use in app navigation)` --> Per my understanding, in your blazor wsam(SPA) - backend server(web api) structure, you should have codes to send http request which also set Bearer token in request header, am I right? At first when I noticed you mentioned opening a new tab page, I feel that shouldn't be a good practice since we are using blazor, all the contents should display in the origin tab but it shouldnt be the case.

Comment: But you mentioned using navigation can work well without having authorisation headers or bearer tokens on the request.. It's really weird, I'm afraid we can use fiddler to capture the traces to see whether there's any authorization information inside the request.

Comment: Yeah that's what's confusing me, the protected endpoints work just fine when normally navigating the app even though I don't see any auth headers, but the moment I reload the protected endpoints throw an error, so it seems just the auth state gets lost

Comment: that doesn't make sense for troubleshooting the issue, could you please help check whether you had any different configurations than the official sample?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/sample-v2-code?tabs=apptype

Comment: I scaffolded the app using the provided WASM template, I didn't really touch it otherwise beyond providing a template that wraps the entire app and redirects to login. I quickly made an Azure AD tenant to test and everything worked immediately so didn't touch it beyond that.

Comment: sorry, it looks weird for me as I never had similar experience before.

Comment: We figured it out, turns out it was an issue with state management in the backend. The backend assumed that the path would always be overview > detail, and didn't take into account people going straight to detail skipping overview, so permissions weren't set correctly